# Optimal HTML & Javascript to create a synchronized timeline

Tags: javascript, html, css, drag-and-drop

I'm working on an application (https://github.com/xOPERATIONS/maestro) that involves scheduling multiple people to perform activities in parallel. Activities may be done independently, or they may be joint between multiple actors. Joint activities must be done concurrently. See the image below for an example.

[Example of SVG timeline with synchronized activities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uzpxk.png)

This is an annotated screenshot of the SVG timeline that the application currently generates for insertion into an MS Word document. The goal is to move away from the Word output and towards a web-based approach. In order to do this, I need to generate the above timeline with HTML. The basic format I've tried so far is:

```html
<div id="timeline">
  <div class="person-wrapper">
    <div class="header">Person 1</div>
    <div class="individual-timeline">
      <div class="activity">
        <span class="title">Activity 0</span> <span class="duration">(00:40)</span>
      </div>
      <div class="activity">
        <span class="title">Activity 1</span> <span class="duration">(00:45)</span>
      </div>
      <!-- ...repeat for each activity... -->

      <!-- if an activity has a synchronization gap above it, calculate 
           pixels from duration of gap and use margin -->
      <div class="activity" style="margin-top:300px;">
        <span class="title">Activity 9</span> <span class="duration">(00:45)</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- ...repeat for Person 2... -->
</div>
```

This gets the basic layout. See the example below.

[Basic layout achieved via HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RpSb.png)

One thing this basic format does not have is the time markings on the left and right side and the corresponding lines. These in particular I'm not sure how to best implement with HTML. Additionally, the timeline will eventually be editable by drag-and-drop, which perhaps impacts the HTML structure. Any suggestions on how to implement that drag-and-drop are appreciated, too. The synchronized blocks complicate this, since they effectively are one event existing in two lists simultaneously.

What is the optimal way to build this in HTML? Is my current prototype good for the content of the timeline? How should I do the times and time-markings? Thanks in advance!

Comment: See this for an example of building a schedule with CSS Grid, may help: https://css-tricks.com/building-a-conference-schedule-with-css-grid/

Comment: Will CSS grid work if blocks can be any arbitrary height? In the conference schedule example I think all blocks are multiples of 30 minutes. What if an event is 29 minutes? I suppose the grid could have hundreds of rows, but I’m not sure that’s optimal. Or perhaps I don’t understand CSS grid (I probably don’t :-) )

Comment: Funny enough, I too am a newbie at CSS Grid, was just hoping that might point you in the right direction :) if you're looking for minute-precision (pun not intended), then I'm not sure that'll work very well... Will your entire `div` have a fixed height? If you do, you could take positioning into your own hands and use some absolute positioning. Would probably take more JS than CSS at that point, though.